# Trying to use a data tag and click event to trigger a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a page and I am trying to reload the page on click and execute a function. This code works on Safara and Firefox, but it doesnt work on Chrome and im not sure about IE. Hoping someone can help me. Below is my code. Not sure if there is a better way of doing this.

Basically i am just create a URL and on click passing a data tag and then grabbing the data tag and assigning the category to the end of a url. Then i am executing the category url function that is called "#tomatoes". I have to reload the page because the function is already called earlier.

```
var categoryTitle = 'Tomatoes';
$('.activeCategory').html('<a href="#" class="activeCategory" data-caturl="#tomatoes">' + categoryTitle + '</a>');

//change the category dynamically if clicked from individual product page
      $('.activeCategory').click(function(event) {
          var caturl = $(this).children('a').data('caturl');
          var newWindow = window.location.href="http://www.example.com/DEV/product-categories/example.php" + caturl;
          if (newWindow === "http://www.example.com/DEV/product-categories/example.php" + caturl) {
              location.reload();
              $("caturl").click();
          } 
      });
```

Comment: can you please post html also?

Comment: Try to include a working example please. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reload the page and add hashtag `#` and then execute your function. There is no way to have a callback on page reload, because your JS application gets re-initialized and starts all over again.

```
var categoryTitle = 'Tomatoes';
$('.activeCategory').html('<a href="#" class="activeCategory" data-caturl="#tomatoes">' + categoryTitle + '</a>');

//change the category dynamically if clicked from individual product page
      $('.activeCategory').click(function(event) {
          var caturl = $(this).children('a').data('caturl');
          var newWindow = window.location.href="http://www.example.com/DEV/product-categories/example.php" + caturl;
          if (newWindow === "http://www.example.com/DEV/product-categories/example.php" + caturl) {
              if(window.location.hash) {
                $("caturl").click();
              } else {
                 window.location = window.location.href + "#refresh";
                 location.reload();
              }



          } 
      });
```

Comment: is there a way i can reset the click event? because these functions are already initialized prior to running this code. which is why i need to refresh the page. the click event wont work unless page is first reloaded

Comment: Try wrapping it in `$( document ).ready(function(){ //place your code here })`. This basically means "A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."

Comment: if i put location.reload(); before the cat url click function it works. not sure why this is. but still doesnt on chrome

Comment: Are you trying to call the `click` event on `caturl` element by `$("caturl").click()`? If so, I would use `$("caturl").trigger("click")` instead.

Comment: it tells me that its undefined

Comment: Do you have the `click` event defined on the `caturl` element? If not, you need to define it `$("caturl").click(function() { ...your code })`

Comment: caturl is invoking another function (I have a function called #tomatoes that has a click event). so $("caturl").trigger("click") is being changed to $("#tomatoes").trigger("click"). since im pasing the hash from the url and adding it to a new click event to call the old one again

Comment: So does `$("#tomatoes").trigger("click")` work then?

Comment: yes but i think the problem is that im already inside a click event to begin with.

Comment: It is hard to see what is going on without looking at what you have. Can you copy and paste everything in jsfiddle and send me the link?

Comment: sure thank you! its a lot though it might be hard to understand whats going on

Comment: When you are inside another event function for a particular element, the keyword `this` points to the context of the element, not the global scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135292/discussion-between-tom-and-tumen-t).